# Sorting in Clisp

Tags: sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort, clisp

I want to write an insertion sort and a merge sort in clisp. The input will be a flat list of numbers. How would one write these 2 sorts recursively (preferably without using lambdas)? For the insertion sort I was thinking of making a function that takes the list and an integer (which is meant to be the current index of the element of interest) as arguments, and using setf and nth to manipulate the list. I know there's also supposed to be another recursive function inside that one, but like... I just get confused with so many functions and variables to store and stuff.

For merge sort I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge sort is naturally recursive (as is any divide and conquer problem)

[http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(Lisp)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_%28Lisp%29)

The insertion sort implementation they have cited is sort of anti-functional

[http://en.literateprograms.org/Insertion_sort_(Lisp)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Insertion_sort_%28Lisp%29)

But loops can easily be turned into tail recursion instead.

Comment: Not that Common Lisp is guaranteed to be tail recursive, but most implementations do that as an implementation detail.

Comment: The merge looks okay, but the insertion one is a bit... crazy. This is precisely why I came here--I have no clue what any of that looping syntax or "finally", or "aref", or "1+/1-", or "flet" stuff is.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's an old question but I was also courious how to write an recursive implementation of Mergesort in Common Lisp style so I wrote it this way :

```
(defun mergesort (lo hi)
  (let ((mid 0)
  (items 0))

  ;; initializations
  (setq items (- hi lo))
  (multiple-value-bind (intreg rest)
  (floor (/ (+ hi (1+ lo)) 2))
    (setq mid intreg))

  ;; recursive call if more than 1 item
  (cond ((> items 1)
    (mergesort lo mid)
    (mergesort mid hi)))

  ;; merge step
  (let ((temp (sort-range *unsorted-list* lo mid hi)))
  (do ((x lo (1+ x))
   (tx 0 (1+ tx)))
  ((= x hi))
(setf (nth x *unsorted-list*) (nth tx temp))))
))

;; collect and sort range between low and high
(defun sort-range (LIST lo mid hi)
  (labels ((collect-range (i1 i2)
     (if (and (< i1 mid) (< i2 hi))
     (let ((lv (nth i1 LIST))
           (rv (nth i2 LIST)))

       (if(and (< lv rv) (< i1 mid))
          (cons lv (collect-range (1+ i1) i2))
          (if(<= i2 hi)
         (cons rv (collect-range i1 (1+ i2))))
          ))
     (if (< i1 mid)
         (cons (nth i1 LIST) (collect-range (1+ i1) i2))
         (if(< i2 hi)
        (cons (nth i2 LIST) (collect-range i1 (1+ i2)))))
     )))
(collect-range lo mid)))
```

Any suggestions are welcomed !